# How to convert LINQ query to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have one LINQ query using join and i don't have enough knowledge about LINQ i want to convert this query in SQL please help me thank you.
In code i post LINQ Query please help me to convert this query in sql.

```
var secUserList = (from secUser in dc.sec_users
                   join userRoles in dc.sec_user_roles
                   on secUser.user_id equals userRoles.user_id
                   join secUserAuth in dc.sec_user_authentications
                   on secUser.user_id equals secUserAuth.user_id
                   where userRoles.role_id == roleId
                   orderby secUser.first_name
                   select new { secUser, secUserAuth });
```

Comment: What is the exact error code and the converted sql query you have tried?

Comment: non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Comment: Well, what is that `equals` thing you use in the `on` clauses?

Comment: = (equals) operator for match two column value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is pretty straight forward one, isn't it ?

```
SELECT secUser.*, secUserAuth.*  
FROM sec_users secUser
INNER JOIN sec_user_roles userRoles
   ON secUser.user_id = userRoles.user_id
INNER JOIN sec_user_authentications secUserAuth
   ON secUser.user_id = secUserAuth.user_id
WHERE userRoles.role_id = roleId
ORDER BY secUser.first_name
```